# is there any modifications i can apply to this code to make it cleaner

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So on my journey of learning react I've built this simple app , It renders a quote from an API and display it with every button click , I've run to issues when i tried to display the quote and I've used some vanilla JavaScript.
Here's my code

```
function App() {
 const [error , setError] = useState(null);
 const [isLoaded ,setIsLoaded] = useState(false);
 const [dataQuotes , setDataQuotes] = useState([]);

 useEffect(() => {
  fetch('https://type.fit/api/quotes')
   .then(res => res.json())
   .then(
    (results) => {
      setIsLoaded(true)
      setDataQuotes(results)
    },
    (error) => {
      setIsLoaded(true)
      setError(error)
    }
   )
 },[])

function getQuote(){
  const Quotes = dataQuotes
  const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*Quotes.length)
  const finalData = Quotes[randomNumber]?.text
  document.getElementById('content').innerHTML=`"${finalData}"`
  
  
}

 
if (error) {
  return <div>Error :{error.message}</div>
} else if (!isLoaded) {
   return <div>Loading...</div>
} else {
  return (
    <>
    <div className='container'>
    <h3 id='content'>{}</h3>
    </div>
    <button onClick={getQuote} className='btn'>Generate Quotes</button>
    </>
  );
  }

}
```

Is there any modifications i can apply to make the code cleaner , because I feel like I can make it better and cleaner

Comment: Head over to [Code Review SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Stack Overflow is for general programming questions, so this question would be better suited there

Comment: i've never heard of this,
indeed the question will be better there 
i appreciate it .

Comment: You should not be using the DOM API to modify content, especially as a first round. Are you doing that because your API response has HTML in it? First of all, I'd try to solve this without HTML styling from some external source. But if you must, and trust it, look up `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`.

Answer (score 1):

Most of it looks clean already. I have pointed out a few changes below.

```js
function App() {
 const [error , setError] = useState(null);
 const [isLoaded ,setIsLoaded] = useState(false);
 const [dataQuotes , setDataQuotes] = useState([]);
 const ref = useRef();

 useEffect(() => {
  fetch('https://type.fit/api/quotes')
   .then(res => res.json())
   .then(
    (results) => {
      setIsLoaded(true)
      setDataQuotes(results)
    },
    (error) => {
      setIsLoaded(true)
      setError(error)
    }
   )
 },[])

function getQuote(){
  const Quotes = dataQuotes
  const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*Quotes.length)
  const finalData = Quotes[randomNumber]?.text
  //document.getElementById('content').innerHTML=`"${finalData}"`
  ref.current.innerHTML = finalData
  
}

return (
    <>
    {error ?
        <div>Error :{error.message}</div>
     :
     !isLoaded ?
        <div>Loading...</div>
     :
     <>
    <div className='container'>
    <h3 id='content' ref={ref}>{}</h3>
    </div>
    <button onClick={getQuote} className='btn'>Generate Quotes</button>
    </>
   }
   </>
  );
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two times `setIsLoaded(true)`: one in `.then` and another in `.error`.
You can use `.finally(() => { setIsLoaded(true) }`.